# System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001 because of Duplicate Records

Tags: limits, duplicate-management

I have Limitations error.
Found out that i am adding Duplicate values to the List.
How do i verify that i am not adding Duplicates.

```
public void financialAccountforContactAndAccounts(List<Financial_Account_role__c> newFinancialAccountRoles)
    {
        if(!recursivetriggerhelper.isaccessTeamTriggerAccount()){ 
        system.debug('***Entering****');
        Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<ID>();
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<ID>();
        Set<Id> accountIdListforAST = new Set<Id>();

        Map<Id,Id> roleIdToTeamId = getRoleToTeamId();
        Map<Id,Id> accountFAcctMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        List<Financial_Account_Role__c> fARoles = [select Financial_Account__c,contact__c,contact__r.accountid,contact__r.ownerid,contact__r.roleid__c,Organization__c,Organization__r.ownerid, Organization__r.roleid__c from Financial_Account_Role__c where id IN: newFinancialAccountRoles];
        for(Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles)
        {
            if(far.contact__c != null)
            {
                contactIds.add(far.contact__c); 
                accountFAcctMap.put(far.contact__r.accountid,far.financial_account__c);               
            }
            else if(far.organization__c != null)
            {
                accountIds.add(far.Organization__c);
                accountIdListforAST.add(far.Organization__c);
                accountFAcctMap.put(far.Organization__c,far.financial_Account__c);
            }
        }

        Map<Id,Contact> contactList= new Map<Id,Contact>([select AccountId from Contact where Id IN :contactIds]);

        for(Contact c:contactList.values())
        {
            accountIdListforAST.add(c.accountid);
        }

        List<AccountTeamMember> accountAsts = [select userid,Accountid  from AccountTeamMember where accountid in: accountIdListforAST];

        List<Financial_Account__Share> listFAShares = new List<Financial_Account__Share>(); 
        system.debug('##faroles'+FARoles);
        for(Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles) 
        {
            system.debug('##newcon'+far.contact__c); 
            system.debug('##newacc'+far.Organization__c);     
            if(far.contact__c!=null)
            {

                 system.debug('****insertFAShare****');
                 Financial_Account__Share faShare = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShare.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShare.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShare.UserOrGroupID = far.contact__r.ownerId;

                 if(far.contact__r.roleid__c !=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.contact__r.roleid__c) != null)
                 {
                 Financial_Account__Share faShareForTeam = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShareForTeam.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShareForTeam.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShareForTeam.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID = roleIdToTeamId.get(far.contact__r.roleid__c);
                 listFAShares.add(faShareForTeam);
                 }

                 for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
                 {
                     if(ast.accountid == far.contact__r.accountid)
                     {
                         Financial_Account__Share faShareForATM= new Financial_Account__Share();
                         faShareForATM.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                         faShareForATM.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                         faShareForATM.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                         faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID = ast.userid;
                         listFAShares.add(faShareForATM);
                     }
                 }


                 listFAShares.add(faShare);

            }    
            else if(far.Organization__c!=null)
            {
                //FAShare added for org owner
                 Financial_Account__Share faShare = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShare.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShare.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShare.UserOrGroupID = far.Organization__r.ownerId;

                 //FAShare added for org owner team
                 if((far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null)
                 {
                 Financial_Account__Share faShareForTeam = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShareForTeam.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShareForTeam.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShareForTeam.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID = roleIdToTeamId.get(far.Organization__r.roleid__c);
                 listFAShares.add(faShareForTeam);
                 }

                 for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
                 {
                     if(ast.accountid == far.organization__c)
                     {
                         Financial_Account__Share faShareForATM= new Financial_Account__Share();
                         faShareForATM.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                         faShareForATM.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                         faShareForATM.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                         faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID = ast.userid;
                         listFAShares.add(faShareForATM);
                     }
                 }  
                 listFAShares.add(faShare);
             }         
        } 
        system.debug('FAShares'+listFAShares);  
        if(listFAShares.size() > 0)
        {
            Database.insert(listFAShares,false);
        }
        }
        recursivetriggerhelper.isaccessTeamTriggerAccount(); 
    }
```

Comment: Use sets and maps

Comment: What's your criteria to say that two `Financial_Account__Share` sObjects are duplicated? that would be the key to use in a set/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**

Ok, After a bit of a discussion, the best way to fix this is probably to use a dual key map.

Since you are really only interested in the `ParentId` and the `UserOrGroup` id, you need to create a composite key of these two values to create a map that you insert the Share values into.

So, define a  Map and put your account share records into it with the key being a concatenation of `UserOrGroupId` and `ParentId`.

at the end grab your `Map` `values()` and insert. Job Done.

---

**UPDATE - This works, but may not be reliable for this specific situation**

To demonstrate what @Eric is saying, run this code snippet

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'hey', StageName = 'Blah', CloseDate = Date.today());

Opportunity[] opps = new Opportunity[]{};
opps.add(opp);
opps.add(opp);
System.debug(opps); //will print out two opps here

Opportunity[] dedupedOpps = new List<Opportunity>(new Set<Opportunity>(opps));
System.debug(dedupedOpps); //will print out one opp here
```

Comment: Using `Set<SObject>` is unreliable at best...and not necessary here. I didn't even know that signature would compile. (does it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45074/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-caspar-harmer).

Answer (score 1):

@Caspar's solution should work, however reviewing your code it looks to me like the only difference between all the `Financial_Account__Share` records that you create is the value set on `UserOrGroupID`. That said, a Map `UserOrGroupID -> Financial_Account__Share` is the fastest solution.

```
// First 42 lines omitted
Map<String, Financial_Account__Share> listFAShares = new Map<String, Financial_Account__Share>();
for(Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles) 
{
    if(far.contact__c!=null)
    {
        // Create record code omitted
        listFAShares.put(faShare.UserOrGroupID, faShare);
        if(far.contact__r.roleid__c !=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.contact__r.roleid__c) != null)
        {
            // Create record code omitted
            listFAShares.put(faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID, faShareForTeam);
        }

        for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
        {
            if(ast.accountid == far.contact__r.accountid)
            {
                // Create record code omitted
                listFAShares.put(faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID, faShareForATM);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(far.Organization__c!=null)
    {
        // FAShare added for org owner
        // Create record code omitted
        listFAShares.put(faShare.UserOrGroupID, faShare);

        //FAShare added for org owner team
        if((far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null)
        {
            // Create record code omitted
            listFAShares.put(faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID, faShareForTeam);
        }

        for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
        {
            if(ast.accountid == far.organization__c)
            {
                // Create record code omitted
                listFAShares.put(faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID, faShareForATM);
            }
        }
    }
}
system.debug('FAShares'+listFAShares);  
if(listFAShares.size() > 0)
{
    Database.insert(listFAShares.values(),false);
}
```

However, considering that your code's logic seems to tend to create an average of 3 `Financial_Account__Share` records for each `Financial_Account_role__c`, I think that eventually you may end up needing a batch class to guarantee that your process will be completed successfully regardless of the number of records that you're going to read/create.